# Symbolic link in High Sierra breaks when the file is modified

Tags: symlink

I have a file named `file.ext`. I create an symbolic link to this file named `file_symlink.ext` in other folder.

When I modify `file.ext` directly (without opening the file *via* the symbolic link), the symbolic link is transformed to an effective file with the old version.

Is that normal?

I would like the symbolic link to always point to the real file, but I can't use alias because LaTeX does not accept working with aliases.

Is there any solution?

It is the last but one file.

```
colas-3:sources colas$ ls -li
total 48
...
8592287609 lrwxr-xr-x  1 colas  staff    116 11 aoû 16:15 exercices_relations.tex symlink -> /Users/colas/Dropbox/Maths/Maths_2018_2019/C. Exercices, DM, Interros/7. Relations/exercices/exercices_relations.tex
8592305400 -rw-r--r--@ 1 colas  staff  22016 11 aoû 18:25 exercices_suites.tex symlink
8592287688 lrwxr-xr-x  1 colas  staff    138 11 aoû 16:16 exercices_systemes_lineaires.tex symlink -> /Users/colas/Dropbox/Maths/Maths_2018_2019/C. Exercices, DM, Interros/9. Systèmes linéaires/exercices/exercices_systemes_lineaires.tex
```

Comment: With which application do you edit `file.ext`? And why can't you run LaTeX directly on the file?

Comment: And I have some troubles understanding "the symbolic link is transformed to an effective file with the old version", can you add some output of `ls -li` demonstrating this?

Comment: I edit `file.ext` with [TeXShop](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/). Actually, I `include` the files with the symlinks.

Comment: Strangely, I cannot reproduce the issue...

Comment: @nohillside It came again. I have updated the question.

Comment: So TeXShop seems to rewrite included files somehow. Not sure you can prevent this from happening, I would probably just run LaTeX directly in the Dropbox folder.

Comment: How are you creating the symlink?  Try this command:  `ln -s /Users/colas/Dropbox/Maths/Maths_2018_2019/C. Exercices, DM, Interros/7. Relations/exercices/exercices_relations.tex /some/other/directory/exercises_relations.tex`

Comment: I use an app called [SymbolicLinker](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker)

Comment: @nohillside Maybe it is related but while I edit the file with `TeXShop` an alert pops: "Your file has been modified by another app. Do you really wish to save?"